# Detect encoding of JPEG in an XML Node

Tags: xml, encoding, jpeg

I have xml that has a jpeg values in xml nodes. How can I detect what the encoding is? It is not in CDATA.

starts like this:

```
<Image>0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB0043000302020302020303030304030304050805050404050A070706080C0A0C0C0B0A0B0B0D0E12100D0E110E0B0B10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would either need to convert to binary and do numeric comparisons or write your own string comparisons.

This looks like a JPEG FFD8 is a start of image marker. 
FFE0 is an APP0 marker. 
4A464946 is the JFIF identifier.

You have a JPEG stream in JFIF format there.